# How do I use RKResponseDescriptor with an id?

Tags: ios, restkit

I am trying to create a RKResponseDescriptor to get people in a session.

I have a response descriptor for /sessions but I don't know how to create it to get the people in the sessions /sessions/20/people (/sessions/sessionID/people).

My session response descriptor is;

```
RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:sessionsMapping
                                                                                   pathPattern:@"/sessions"
                                                                                       keyPath:nil
                                                                                   statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
```

The response descriptor for the people in the session is;

```
RKResponseDescriptor *clientInSessionResponseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:clientsInSessionMapping
                                                                                   pathPattern:@"/sessions/:sessionID/people"
                                                                                       keyPath:nil
                                                                                   statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
```

I keep getting the error, "Failed with error: No response descriptors match the response loaded."

I noticed in the documentation there is a lot of usage of the :id but can't seem to figure it out.  Also, should I use a RKPathMatcher to build the path?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was a parameter substitution when sending the request path.  So in your case I would do the following:

```
NSString *idValue; // this is the sessionID value
NSString *path = [@"/sessions/:sessionID/people" stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@":sessionID" withString:idValue];
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObjectsAtPath:path parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation,RKMappingResult *mappingResult) 
{
  // handle success
} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    RKLogError(@"*** RK load FAIL");
}]
```